# Recycler View Retrieving Childs of different Nodes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[[image: [1]]

I am planning to retrieve data for a recycler view from the node "movies" and "tickets". I am using Android Studio.

Till now I have a code to retrieve data just from the node "movies".
Is there a possibility to add something to the code to be able to retrieve data from "tickets" also in the same RecycleView?

Thanks for your help :)

```
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference mRef;

    // send query to firebaseDatabase
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    // the following line i suppose needs to change to "Cities"
    mRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Cities/movies");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Movie, MovieViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Movie, MovieViewHolder>(
                    Movie.class,
                    R.layout.movies_all,
                    MovieViewHolder.class,
                    mRef
            ){

@Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(MovieViewHolder viewHolder, Movie movie, int position){
                    viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(),
      // the following line(s) again needs to change, but I don't know to what
                            movie.getTickets(),
                            movie.getKino(),
                            movie.getTime();

                }
```

Edit: Or do I need a second "ViewHolder.class" and a second "FirebaseRecyclerAdapter" to retrieve from different nodes?

Comment: I’m afraid FirebaseRecyclerAdapter doesn’t support multiple requests/sources. You’ll have to request your data manually and then fill your RecyclerView.

Comment: If I requested the data before - how can I fill it into the populate Viewer? Or where do I have to fill it for the recycler View?

Comment: Just create your own RecyclerView.Adapter as you do for any other RecyclerView.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help :)